# How can I run git submodules?

Tags: git

I am trying to make use of Wikislurp to dynamically read Wikipedia articles.

The readme file states the following:

After you have clone the repository, you'll need to run the following to
pull in all the submodules:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
cd externals/curlcall
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

But how do I do this? I have no experience with git whatsoever and a search didn't give me anything usable.

Comment: Here's the url:
http://github.com/NeilCrosby/wikislurp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to install Git for this...